# Ui-router: How to get next state params in transition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router 1.0.0.beta.3. How can get I route parameters of next state during a transition?

index.run.js

```
$transitions.onStart({ to: '**' }, verifyAuth);

function verifyAuth(trans) {
  let nextState = trans.$to();
  if (Auth.verify(nextState.authGroup) === -1) {      
    return $state.go('login', { nextState: nextState.name, nextParams: nextState.params}); // this doesn't work
  }
}
```

I want to store them so I can redirect the user to the state + state params he was trying to access, after authentication is succeeded.

login.component.js

```
let nextState = this.$stateParams.nextState;
let nextParams = this.$stateParams.nextParams;
$state.go(nextState, nextParams);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the answer to your question is [`Transition.params()`](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#params)

```
function verifyAuth(trans) {
  let nextState = trans.to();
  let nextParams = trans.params();
  if (Auth.verify(nextState.authGroup) === -1) {      
    return $state.go('login', { nextState: nextState.name, nextParams: nextParams});
  }
}
```

---

However, I recommend studying how the [ui-router 1.0 sample app](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-ng1/) performs authentication checks and login redirects:

This hook *redirects the unauthenticated transition* to the login state by returning a `$state.target('login')`

https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-ng1/blob/master/app/global/requiresAuth.hook.js#L15-L24

In the login state, the "state to return to after login" is determined.  It checks the original transition's destination using `Transition.redirectedFrom()`.

https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-ng1/blob/master/app/main/app.states.js#L44-L83

Comment: Good answer but, as an addendum, if you're stuck with a legacy project that can't handle that much refactoring in one go, on 1.0.5 I found I could use `trans.$to()` and `trans.$from()` as drop in replacements. Hopefully I can refactor it some more again sometime to go with the sample app's strategy.

Comment: I was looking for this desperately. Feeling angry for not googling properly and jumping to the source code for their library. They have unnecessarily complicated documentation and library design.